# How to add update function into phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova

Does phonegap allow us to update the app we created if I want to add or change something later on?

For example, I created an app and installed on my Android cellphone. Now I want to change some content of this app. Is that possible to achieve that without installing the full .apk file again?

A similar question here: [How to update app with phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401086/how-to-update-app-with-phonegap)
However,the answer "update them in your project then submit a new apk to Google Play" still makes me confused -- submitting a new apk to google then my installed app would know there is a new version? and would update??

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. You cannot update the app in user cellphone unless your app force user to update the app. IBM Worklight can do force update.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put you html files on live server and change it from there. Suppose your files are in `www.example.com` site. Like `www.example.com/main.html` You can refer to this link from your phonegap app. And you can control it as you wish without forcing any installation.

But it comes with a price. Your app user have to be connected to internet for full time.